# Email template Preview shows lots of records even though its not related to anything

Tags: email, email-template

I just want to know how does the Email template review work. I have created a VF email template and added few VF components in it. The email template related to Custom Object,and in VF components, I am fetching all the Open task related to this Custom Object by passing Obj Id in parameter , then query records on basis of ID . When I open the email template, in preview even though is not related to any custom object ID,all the Open task in the org coming up. 
I checked the debug log , but nothing is there. In VF query, i have the WHERE clause well. Why still all the task in coming in preview.

How does this Email template Preview works.

Comment: Can you post how you are trying to pass the Obj Id param to the template?

Comment: It'll help if you post the query, it sounds like your using criteria in such a way that if they're null it will pull in all records